# How can I find semantically similar paragraph in two different text files (two documents)

Tags: nlp, gensim, recurrent-neural-network

I have found so many similar questions none of them answer my problem can Someone help me . I have two legal documents I need to find which are contextually same or have same meaning what should be my approach. I thought of use something with LSTM wherever I see i get people having one or two sentences to compare . I want to do it for lot of docs and find out which of them are similar cannot get my head around how to begin my task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are describing the purpose behind Doc2Vec. You can train this model to produce document vectors which can be used for measuring similarity. If you have heard of Word2Vec, this is related to that at the document level. You will likely need to tweak the model to get it to work how you want it to, but this is probably a good start at least.

[Doc2Vec Official Documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html)

[Doc2Vec Tutorial](https://medium.com/scaleabout/a-gentle-introduction-to-doc2vec-db3e8c0cce5e)